# How to kill all process of a program?

Tags: bash, kill, ps

Sometimes I get some problem with Skype or Netbeans. So, when I want to kill all processes of them and restart them the only way I know is to perform

```
$ ps aux | grep skype
```

get all process id

```
abdemo    3396  1.7  2.2 323800 89788 ?        Sl   Jun18  45:48 skype
abdemo   18871 11.8  1.8 254248 74836 ?        Sl   13:14   0:04 skype
abdemo   19009  0.0  0.0   9424   924 pts/0    S+   13:15   0:00 grep --color=auto skype
```

and kill all by hand.

```
$ sudo kill 3396 18871 19009
```

It work. But I think there is a better way to do this. Can you suggest me the better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[killall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) is your friend

```
killall skype
```

You only need to use sudo if the process is owned by another user e.g.

```
sudo killall gdm
```

Comment: `killall` does the job but `sudo` is really not needed, these are user processess.

Comment: Yes.  The OP was using `sudo`, hence I did too, but it's probably not needed for these examples.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

'killall' is the way to go. As an alternative you can use

```
pidof skype
```

to get all the pids; don't use the `ps` thingie if you know the name of the process.

Combine that with a regular kill

```
kill `pidof skype`
```